# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Chrome web store screen shuts off

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, screen

I'm fairly new at this other-OS-than-windows-thing, so I might have a hard time understanding and using the proper names for stuff...

so, I'm trying to get netflix to work on my laptop running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. There are some guides out there and I'm currently following this one: http://www.webupd8.org/2014/08/how-to-enable-html5-playback-for.html

I'm at step 3 (Install the User-Agent Switcher) where I have to go to the chrome web store and get an extension. Fairly normal stuff, a baby could do it. However, as soon as the page loads my screen shuts off and I can't get it back to life. After forcing my computer to restart the screen is back on and works fine. I've tried opening the link to the web store in firefox without this issue and it loads fine (but of course I can't get the extension), so it's something with chrome that is messing with me. 
Also, I've tried pressing the lock-buttons (caps, scroll and num), the light works so the system at least recognize input.
Anyone else have this problem?
I've tried to google it, but I haven't found anything that reminds me of this.

Halp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem. For me, solution was to disable hardware acceleration. This isn't the best solution because Youtube videos are not smooth and are choppy when you disable HWA, but that is the only solution I managed to find.

Hope this will help you until someone gives better solution.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was reported on chromium bug reporting system. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=443424 
Basically te fix is to update your graphics driver. E.g.

"I went to https://01.org/linuxgraphics/ and downloaded the "Graphics Installer 1.0.7 for Ubuntu 14.04, 64-bit", which was a .deb package. I installed this using gdebi, then ran it. It took over my system for ~15 minutes while it updated my Intel graphics drivers. After a reboot, Chrome seems to be free of the "black screen" issue. "